# Communication between Raspberry Pi, GSM module and database

Tags: python, mysql, gsm, raspberry-pi3

I'm just learning about Raspberry Pi. How can I communicate Raspberry Pi with database, so that can Raspberry Pi send message/sms using GSM module? and  how the Raspberry Pi read databases MySQL from different tables that could be sent in a single sentence using GSM?

Comment: Nice try @adew.
What the down-voting people did't do was to tell you why.

I spent some time trying to answer your questions & also given you some advice for the future. I suggest you read all of it.

So keep asking questions. I know the next one you ask will be great!

Answer (score 1):

To start with

**GSM module communication:**

This question has many different answers and the answer depends on what hardware you will use. There is no standard in this area.

To give you some options;

- https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9533
- https://www.adafruit.com/products/2636

Sparkfun will provide you with a detailed datashet & Adafruit even has a detailed tutorial. The drawback with the Adafruit tutorial is that it assumes that you are using a arduino (Not a big problem)

Both of the above modules are capable of UART communication, something you easily can access with a RaspberryPI and

- http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html
- https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Python

Personally I have used WiringPI before and it is easy to start with and has a bunch of active maintainers on IRC.

To wrap up the GSM-part. Consult the manual for that particular device you are going to use. That is the only way you will know what to send and what you will receive from the module.

**Database querys:**

Are you using a existing database or are you going to create your own from scratch?
Even that part of the question is to broad.

If you are going to make a new database just for this kind of application I might suggest using

- https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

It will give you a nice little ORM tool. It will make it easy for you to insert and fetch data that probably matches how you want to work with the data.

If the database is a existing MySQL database

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-examples.html

Well again, consult the manual.